why printf is not giving any output even though program is running?
i was expecting a output asking score but no printf fnx is working.
#include<stdio.h>
float percentage(float a, float b, float c);

float main(){
    float a,b,c;
    printf("enter sci marks: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("enter maths marks: ");
    scanf("%f",&b);
    printf("enter sans marks: ");
    scanf("%f",&c);
    float var = percentage(a,b,c);
    printf(" percentage = %f", var);
    return 0;
}
float percentage(float a,float b,float c){
    float var = (a + b + c)/3.0 ;
    return var; 
}


was expecting the program to ask for all three inputs and then give percentage.

Look in the OUTPUT tab, I bet you'll see them there.

Why is main declared to return float? That's a new one for me.

@Barmar output is blank

@Chris its not throwing any error coz of that

The VSCode terminal emulator can act weirdly. Does it work in a regular terminal window?

Aside, the function looks as though it should be named average().

sorry but i dint know what is regular terminal window

@KumarMohit but it's not right either.

@Kumar Mohit, I would tell you it's wrong if you "listened" (i.e. enabled warnings, e.g. used -Wall -Wextra -pedantic).

The output doesn't look blank to me, but 33.333332 after only inputting one value.

@Weather Vane The question is about the other three printf...

FYI, it's normal to prompt on stderr, not stdout. stderr is unbuffered by default (so you don't need to flush it to force content that doesn't end in a newline to be printed), and prompts are diagnostic in nature (they're informing the operator about what the next interaction the program requires is), in line with how POSIX defines stderr (as intended for "diagnostic" content).

@CharlesDuffy Even if the prompts are buffered, they should still be printed when the program exits and buffers are flushed. They should print before the percentage message.

@KumarMohit If you're using Windows, it's the Command Prompt.

It’s normal for shells to prompt to stderr. For everything else that’s weird. OP doesn’t seem interested in learning properly anyway. This Q is dead.

@Dúthomhas, prompting on stdout is wrong for non-shell software too. If you're running foo >out.txt, you don't want a prompt from foo to the user to end up in out.txt where it's both polluting your output and not visible to the human operator!

@Dúthomhas, ...as for "dead", 45 minutes after asking seems a bit early to be making that determination. More reasonable to wait at least a few days.

I suspect what may be happening is that your inputs are overwriting the outputs because there are no newlines.

Re main()'s return type:  See What should main() return in C and C++? You are running in a hosted environment. It should be int main() , not float unless your compiler's documentation explicitly says it allows float and you don't ever want to try to compile with a different compiler..

This works just fine on my mac. Clang warns about the float main, but still asks me for three marks, and averages them. I compiled and ran it outside of vscode.

@HackSaw The very definition of breaking the rules of C or C++ is, "it might work, for you, today, on this computer. It's still broken, and just waits to bite you at a more inopportune moment".

I try to keep this quote, and it's spirit, foremost in my mind: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it." --Donald Knuth

The reason for your problem is that you are running the wrong executable file.
The command
gcc percentage.c

will create an executable file named a.exe, not percentage.exe. In the screenshot of your question, you can see that there is a file named a.exe in your working directory.
If you want to instead create an executable file named percentage.exe, you must write the following command:
gcc percentage.c -o percentage.exe

In order to prevent having to type such a long command every time you recompile the program, you may want to consider using a makefile or configuring make in such a way that you only have to type something like:
make percentage


yes that correct.  i am getting the desired output. but why is this happening can u pls elaborate.

@KumarMohit: You are not specifying the name of the output file. With gcc, the default name for an output file is a.out on Linux and a.exe on Windows. If you use the -o command line option, you are overriding this default file name and specifying a different file name for the output file.
